# Reading BLOB type data from SQLite db

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to read some data from sqlite db using python.
all the data looks like the following

```
_��     ;"� m���;"� �jgY    i am good
```

and i am trying to get only the text part "i am good".

i try to look for reading a binary data but i didn't succeed to convert it to readable format.
there is some library that do that?

this is my code in python:

```
 conn = sqlite3.connect('cache4.db')
cursor = conn.execute("select data from messages;")
```

Comment: Are you trying to read a sqlite db file raw with simple file reading operations? or are you using the module `sqlite3`?

Comment: i am using the sqlite 3 module, i edit my question

Comment: You have to find out what format the program that wrote the data uses. You did not tell us anything about that.

Comment: yes, this is the problem, i do not know which format is that...

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: in this case not, but you can use struct lib in order to handle binary data, 
see that link it may help you.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html